# eclipse set source level

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project that I built for jdk 7, but I want to expand its compatibility for jdk 6 users as well. I have set the compiler compilance level to 1.6, but the project compiles normally, and fails running on a 1.6 jre due to the fact that the method revalidate was not added to java until java 7. (and the compiler didn't give ANY warnings about this at all!) How can I set the source level to 1.6 as well? I could do this in netbeans, any way on how to do this in eclipse?

Comment: Change the source for the jre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In project properties->Java Build Path/Libraries tab make sure you have JRE System Library 6 ennvironment

Answer (score 2):

In addition to source compability also set "compiler compliance level" and "generated .class files compatibility" in your project settings.

Comment: yup. I decompiled it and still see the revalidate method there.(No warnings in eclipse, either)

Comment: Have you added any non-standard jars to the build path? And which class is using revalidate?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after setting my compliance level and ensuring I had proper run time. To resolve I had to run Project then Clean... and specify project name.  This took care of the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Properties> Java Compiler > JDK Compliance, make sure to set to proper compiler version.