# How do I create and use a sparse array through ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been at this all day, researching on SO and elsewhere and trying everything I can think of. I've only been using java for 2 weeks now so I'm super new to this and totally confused. I keep getting errors when I try to use ArrayList to create a sparse array with an uncertain length (I take input from the user to determine the length of a corresponding dense array and the density).

```
ArrayList<Double> SparseArray = new ArrayList<Double>[]{
//private ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> SparseArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < DenseArray.length; i++){
        if (DenseArray[i] != 0){
            SparseArray.add(DenseArray[i]);
```

The first two lines of my code are two different things I've tried, both of which come up with the following errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 
 or greater
- Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 
 or greater
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
- Syntax error, insert "ArrayInitializer" to complete 
 ArrayCreationWithArrayInitializer
```

(Edit: the ArrayInitializer error is new, I hadn't seen that until now. If that will solve my problems, how do I go about using it?)

even my "import java.util.ArrayList;" gives me this:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
- Syntax error on token ".", = expected
```

Any ideas would be tremendously appreciated! :)

EDIT: I got the compiler issue taken care of. I still can't figure out how to get it to recognize DenseArray as a variable (it was used just above in the same function except it's now treating ArrayList as a separate function).  I come from the world of Python where I would just default to global variables when these problems happened, but I don't know what to do in java.. is there a java global variable equivalent or something similar?

Comment: Your first line doesn't make much sense (what is that `{` at the end for?). It's not possible to diagnose the errors on your `import` statement without seeing it in context; `import`s have to go at the top of the file, outside of any class definition. Also seems like you are using some odd compiler settings; your compiler is obviously aware of 1.5 but is not using it. How are you compiling your code?

Comment: I added the { at the end because it kept telling me to. I know, I didn't think I was supposed to have one there either, but eclipse (that's what I'm using) seemed pretty insistent.. and I have no idea what compiler settings are or mean.

Comment: Check the settings described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556583/eclipse-set-source-level. Did you create this project from scratch or did you start from an existing project? By the way, you may want to try not using an IDE at first, just to get a feel for how things work behind the scenes. It will make what the IDE does for you make a lot more sense.

Comment: Apart from the Java hiccups: If you condense a "sparse array" the way you apparently intend to do, you lose the information at which index the element was in the original array. Usually, this is highly relevant, unless you have a list of values that happens to be stored in an array from which zeros can be filtered because they aren't relevant.

Comment: Most of the time, error messages aren't the best "programmer advisory" when it comes to fixing coarse syntax errors. After `new ArrayList<Double>` you don't put a pair of brackets `[]` but a pair of parentheses `()`!

Comment: sorry, I had () originally, I just forgot to change them back during my "try-everything-you-can-possibly-think-to-try" spree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
- Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
```

might be due to an incorrect setting of the compiler compliance level in Eclipse.

```
Menu: Window -> Preferences (at the bottom of the menu)
```

In the pop-up window, click on `Java`, which opens a sub-list, where you click on `Compiler`.

There, select "Compiler compliance level" to show 1.7 (or 1.6).

Comment: Or 1.8 - which we now know that you have.

Comment: Ah. Yes, it was set at 1.4. I changed it to 1.7 but it didn't seem to work... I don't know what I did wrong but when I open the menu back up to check, it has been updated to 1.7

Comment: (1.8 wasn't an option)

Comment: nevermind I got the compiler part to work. I still can't figure out how to get it to recognize DenseArray (defined and used above in the same function I think.. unless ArrayList is its own function) as a variable.

Comment: Without any indication where and how it is defined a it's impossible to tell. You need to have something like `double[] DenseArray = new double[123];` in the class where that other method is accessing it. -- There is no such thing as "global data" in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Java generics came out in 1.5. This means that you won't be able to use them unless you are using 1.5 or higher. Just upgrade your Java runtime and the code should compile fine.

- https://www.java.com/en/download/

If you want the code to compile without upgrading (not recommended), then just remove the generics. Just remove all of the `<Double>` and make sure you are careful about your type casting.

Comment: The compiler knows enough to know that generics are available at source level 1.5 or greater; so it seems like it is an appropriate version but with a bad `-source` argument on the command line.

Comment: @JasonC I think you're right. I think that there is some misconfiguration in his project settings.

Comment: So I shouldn't redownload java afterall..?

Comment: @user3345626 just check your Java version by running `java -version` in a commandline.

Comment: @user3345626 your project settings are off. Just change your runtime environment so it's version is greater than or equal to 1.5.