# strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5 [ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i am using Java 1.8.101 version. when i run maven clean install, at that time i am getting error

```
strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch).
```

I don't know why because already i am using java 1.8.101 version.\

Any help would be great.
Thanks a lot in advance for help.
Attached screenshot.

[image: java]

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: @Rajender Pal what role is maven playing here? Please elaborate, might be the cause.

Comment: @jeremy Heiler - where i will find this file in my project?

Comment: It's your pom.xml file.

Comment: @RajenderPal the `pom.xml` that is visible under your project.

Comment: Maybe you use java 1.8 but your project source language level is 1.5. Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556583/eclipse-set-source-level) link

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested by @Jeremy as well, make an entry to the `pom.xml` file as -

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and use `mvn clean install` on the command line to verify the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It worked.